# ExtJS resizable column layout

Tags: layout, extjs, resizable

I am in need of layout with resizable columns. I have a panel with 3 grid panels inside, now I am using hbox layout in the outer panel to organize them and this is ok, but I want to have a separator, like in the border layout, to resize the columns.

how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use border layout then. Put one grid in west region, one in center and one in east region.